# Undergraduate, graduate or post-graduate student — is that Bachelor/Master/PhD or Bachelor/Master+PhD/postdoc?

Tags: terminology

I received an invitation to nominate students for an award that could be for *an undergraduate, a graduate or a post-graduate student*. I've seen those terms used before, but never been sure what they mean. I know *Bachelor* student, *Master* student, *PhD* student and *post-doc*.

The timeline:

Being a Bachelor student → Getting the Bachelor degree → Being a Master student → Getting the Master degree → Being a PhD student → Getting the PhD degree → Being a post-doc → ...

Then what do *undergraduate*, *graduate* and *post-graduate* students refer to? Are *undergraduate* students exclusively students studying to get a *Bachelor* degree, or can it also refer to students studying to get a *Master* degree? After all, that's a graduation that they don't have yet. Literally speaking, it could also be "under" the PhD degree, but that's surely never used as such.

And a *graduate* student, is that then someone studying for the *Master* degree, er is it used only for people studying for the *PhD* degree?

But then what is a *post-graduate student*? Is this a *post-doc*? But *post-doc*s aren't students anymore, so then it could only refer to *PhD* students. Or are post-docs considered students, too?

Comment: In many places, it takes a medical school student 6 or 7 years to be a medical doctor. Where do they fit?

Comment: Now that I have attained a bachelors in business administration and am in the job market it seems that I am not a "graduate" as many of the global corps describe graduates in the qualifications sections as holders of a masters degree. Looks like I'm going back for more. yippee

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am almost certain that post doc is *not* what is meant.

In English speaking systems outside of North America, and especially referring to Europe under the Bologna accords, an *undergraduate* refers to someone who is studying for, but has yet to receive, his *first post-secondary education degree*. Typically this degree is some equivalent of Bachelors, but in some cases students maybe enrolled in accelerated programs with a longer term of study that leads directly to (the equivalent of) a Masters degree.

A *graduate* student can, but not necessarily, refer to someone who is studying for a *graduate diploma*. In many countries having a Bachelors (or equivalent) is not sufficient in itself to qualify one for starting a postgraduate degree. One often requires a "good enough" Bachelors degree (such as one with honors). The graduate diploma is an intermediate step in which a student who has already received his first post-secondary degree studies further in order to qualify to enroll in a masters (or sometimes doctorate? I am not sure about this) degree program.

A *postgraduate* student refers to someone who has already obtained a first degree, and is now pursuing a second, third, or Nth degree beyond it. See, e.g. [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_education).

A postdoctoral researcher is generally *not* considered as a student.

---

In English speaking North America, an *undergraduate* typically refers to someone studying for a bachelors, since almost all (if not all) degree programs go through that stage in North America. And a *graduate student* refers to any student studying for any degree beyond that of the bachelors (so that would be typically the masters or the doctorate).

Comment: @Pacerier: the one example I had in mind is the [Cambridge Math Tripos](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad), where some students can get, after one extra year of course work, both a BA and MMath degree at the same time now. (The offered degree(s) used to be slightly different some years ago, IIRC.) // These sorts of programs were more prevalent before Bologna. For example the pre-Bologna un-tiered Diplom degree in Germany, Austria, and Switzerland is largely the first degree held by the individuals and is currently recognized as largely equivalent to a modern Master's degree.

Comment: Further comment, hopefully clarifying a bit more: according to https://educationusa.state.gov/your-5-steps-us-study/research-your-options/graduate/what-graduate-student , in the US you can pursue a master's *or* a PhD after a bachelor's. In Germany (and most other European countries), you have to obtain a bachelor's degree first, then a master's, then you can pursue a PhD.

Answer (score 1):

In many American Universities, the concept of a Master student is that which is enrolled purely in a Master course, and is expected to leave the school after graduation.

A Graduate student is usually enrolled with the objective of doing a PhD, many Graduate students, provided they have the coursework and thesis, might get a Masters degree in the middle of the program along with the PhD.

Usually for postgraduate students I also think is for post docs, but I'm not sure. In Mexico (and maybe France, because we share some characteristics of the language) a postgraduate student is one doing either a PhD or a Master, and a Graduate student is one doing his Bachelor degree.

Comment: This view isn't really correct. A master's student may _also_ be done as a prelude to a PhD, particularly when the admissions to the doctoral program is not automatic (even when made contingent upon passing a qualifying exam).

Answer (score -3):

In the USA  An undergraduate student is one who's working towards a bachelors degree; typically a graduate student is one who has a bachelors degree and is either working on a Masters are higher level degree; a postgraduate degree level refers to someone who has earned a masters degree and is in route to a higher level degree; a postdoctoral Student is when they have completed coursework for the doctor degree but still has other requirements to finish like a thesis or disertation.

Comment: _In the USA **...**  a postdoctoral Student is when they have completed coursework for the doctor degree but still has other requirements to finish like a thesis or disertation._ [citation needed]